# PHP MySQL page generation without DB generation framework

Tags: php, mysql, database, crud

I'm looking for a web framework that lets me generate CRUD pages for an existing database.

I've tried frameworks like symfony, and even considered rails (completely forgetting php), but those frameworks create and manage the DB for me, and I don't need that.

I need a tool with which you create object-DB mappings, and non-default behavior, and you get your pages generated, but without having to have created the DB with the same framework. I don't mind updating the mappings and the DB migration scripts by myself.

Is there such a wonderful thing in the world?

Edit: In other words, I need a php framework that adapts to my DB structure, not a framework that forces me their DB structure.

Edit2: I'm looking for something similar to xataface, but unfortunately the gpl is enough to freak out any corporate sysadmin.

Comment: Zend Framework, the Db Layer provides methods, and even the start of a persitance layer, but does certainly not enforce usage and create your DB.

Comment: @regilero I haven't really used the Zend Framework, but I don't really want to have to make (many) code changes whenever I have a schema change. In a perfect world, when I add a column to a table, I'd just add one line to the mapping file telling it to use that new column, the name of the label, and the type of control. No more.

Comment: Take a look at this http://www.decodephp.com/category/php-viz/

Comment: that's the way I use Zend Framework. Zend_Db_Table automatically detect new columns, but I add my mapping in my Db layer classes to set some fine settings (how to show, how to edit, how to filter & validate).

Comment: @Sabeen thank you very much for your comment. Your tool seems interesting, but it also seems like it's quite immature (as in code maturity). It's not even version 1, and it looks like only one person is working on it. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

One of these?

http://www.phpframeworks.com/

Comment: Sure, but which one? from what I've seen, most frameworks that generate pages insist on also managing the DB schema for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a misunderstanding of the Rails and some other frameworks when you say they force you to their model.  Rails provides an access layer that is easily adapted to legacy code using the ActiveRecord pattern.  When properly implemented these models introspect on your database schema for the attributes that accesible in your model instance.  So from there you would just need to create the models that are associated with your legacy tables.

The confusion may come from migrations.  In rails you can dump an existing database as your starting point and then write migrations for any changes that you make from that point going forward.

I am sure there are similar facilities in symfony and codeigniter on the PHP side of things.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but the problem is not about the tables being legacy. It's that I just want to be able to easily create and deploy an admin frontend to a db which is handled by a completely different program (which will actually be written in C). In other words, the web application I'm talking about is not the main application, and I don't want schema changes to have to originate from it.